# How can we listen continous without running seperate file for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, microservices

In python Django micro-service, we are using rabbitMQ for internal communication,Now i have to run two terminal for a single service

1. run manage.py
2. run receive.py for consuming

How can we combine this together to listening and run project.

am following this document
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Comment: You have to be more specific about your plans. Usually two terminals means two separate services in separate processes.

Comment: @KlausD. no, for single service 2 terminal were used, 1 -> python manage.py runserver and 2 -> python receive.py (for receiving queue message).Without running receive.py, i didnt receive the message

Comment: Well, that's a 2nd service then.

Comment: @KlausD. i have 2 micro-service A and B. From A i will send a message through rabbitMQ and pika. In second service B, i have run python manage.py run server for running the project and run python receive.py for listening the queue and receive

Comment: You can say that a thousand times, but still you are running two processes and that makes two independent services, three with A included.

Comment: I understand that you want to run both scripts from the same terminal, is this correct?

Comment: @RaulPerez yes, correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try launching in consumer as a background thread.

instead of launching the consumer instruction which halts execution and waits for a new message to be received

```py
channel.start_consuming()
```

you can generate a new thread and associate this function to it.

```py
import threading

#channel.start_consuming()


thread = threading.Thread(name='t', target=channel.start_consuming, args=())
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
```

and then continue with the proudctor's instructions.